# Assigning types from @types to local code?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a method that delegates to validatorjs that looks like this:

```
  /**
   * Checks if the string is a mobile phone number (locale is one of ['zh-CN', 'zh-TW', 'en-ZA', 'en-AU', 'en-HK',
   * 'pt-PT', 'fr-FR', 'el-GR', 'en-GB', 'en-US', 'en-ZM', 'ru-RU', 'nb-NO', 'nn-NO', 'vi-VN', 'en-NZ']).
   * If given value is not a string, then it returns false.
   */
  export function isMobilePhone(value: string, locale: string): boolean {
    return (
      typeof value === "string" && vjsIsMobilePhone(value, locale)
    );
  }
```

VSCode renders the following error for the `locale` parameter:

> [ts] Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MobilePhoneLocale'.
>   (parameter) locale: string

The `MobilePhoneLocale` type comes from `@types/validator`.  If I assign `MobilePhoneLocale` to `locale` (Instead of using string), the method looks like this:

```
    /**
     * Checks if the string is a mobile phone number (locale is one of ['zh-CN', 'zh-TW', 'en-ZA', 'en-AU', 'en-HK',
     * 'pt-PT', 'fr-FR', 'el-GR', 'en-GB', 'en-US', 'en-ZM', 'ru-RU', 'nb-NO', 'nn-NO', 'vi-VN', 'en-NZ']).
     * If given value is not a string, then it returns false.
     */
    export function isMobilePhone(value: string, locale: MobilePhoneLocale): boolean {
      return (
        typeof value === "string" && vjsIsMobilePhone(value, locale)
      );
    }
```

However now ts renders this error:

> [ts] Cannot find name 'MobilePhoneLocale

How should the type of `locale` be implemented by the above function?

Also created an [@types/validator github issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/26969) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MobilePhoneLocale` is declared under the `ValidatorJS` namespace, which is accessible once you import `validator`. You refer to it as `ValidatorJS.MobilePhoneLocale`. Here’s an example using `ts-node`:

```
> import validator = require("validator")
{}
> function foo(l: ValidatorJS.MobilePhoneLocale): ValidatorJS.MobilePhoneLocale { return l; }
undefined
> foo("en-US")
'en-US'
```

Comment: OK - awesome - I did not realize I needed the ValidatorJS part.  Thanks for pointing that out!